# Mouse hover function in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I need to mouse hover an element using capybara. It's working fine in FF15. But not in FF13. Can anybody please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution

```
page.driver.browser.mouse.move_to(page.driver.browser.find_element(:id=>"locator"))
```

It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to simulate "mouse hover" using Capybara + the Selenium driver:

```
module Capybara
  module Node
    class Element
      def hover
        @session.driver.browser.action.move_to(self.native).perform
      end
    end
  end
end
```